# mkdir context example php

Tags: php, mkdir

In php 5.0 context was added to mkdir. But how to use it and what useful things can it do?

And what parameters can be used for context that is passed to mkdir ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the context option was added so that mkdir could be used instead of a connection specific mkdir in PHP like ftp_mkdir:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ftp.php

Although there doesn't seem to be a ton of advantage in adding the context to the mkdir, there is plenty of advantage in adding it to all of the file system creation functions:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.contexts.php

As for the parameters, check this out:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.php

Comment: Yes I know about links you gave but cannot find a context to use with mkdir )

Comment: Cannot find ftp context that can change behavior of mkdir. It seems like not all contexts are documented.

Answer (score 0):

You need two parameters, "folder" and "permissions". Read this: http://php.net/manual/es/function.mkdir.php

I recommend using `chmod()` after `mkdir()`.

http://php.net/manual/es/function.chmod.php

Comment: Why would you recommend using chmod() after mkdir()? Doesn't the second parameter of mkdir() handle the permission? You just send an argument along and it will handle it as if chmod() was called. Correct me if i'm wrong here.